# Problem using string resources in AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I'm a newbie using Android Studio, which I use for a Flutter mobile App project.

In the AndroidManifest.xml file I am trying to set up the required instruction for a Facebook login SDK package.

I do so by first adding a Value resource file and afterwards I add some string resources:

```
<string name="facebook_app_id">6548230980294823</string>
```

When the string resource is referenced in the manifest file it look like this:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
```

Unfortunately, it does not work. Android Studio keeps on claiming that it cannot resolve the string resource:

[image]

I have read countless posts already concerning this problems, but I was not able to find a solution.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Start AndroidStudio (I am using version 3.5.2)
2. Create a new Flutter project
3. Add a new value resource file (name it strings.xml for instance)
4. Add some string resources in the value resource file
5. Use a string resource in the manifest file (AndroidManifest.xml).
   For instance as listed above or elsewhere and otherwise in the
   manifest file.

Results are always the same: "Cannot resolve the symbol ..."

Finally, I have noticed that if I download an example project from a flutter package, which contains references to string resources in the manifest file, this seems to work all-right (the example I am referring to is available here: https://github.com/roughike/flutter_facebook_login).

I have almost spent days on this problem.

Thanks in advance - from a newbie using Android Studio.

Comment: Cannot resolve error always shows even when everything is fine, when you open android module, open your flutter project and hopefully everything will be fine.

Comment: Did you try to run and build the project? When you open it as a flutter project, the files for the android or iOS project aren't precisely identified, so this shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: I was suspecting that the resolve error could be neglected. But I am not sure, it is correct. For the following reason: the example I am referring to in the above do exactly what I am trying to do in my own project. That is, it utilises some Facebook SDK and the strings used to set it up in the manifest resolves nicely. When I run my project, it crash immediately, which seems to indicate that the SDK is not initialised correctly. Recap. I have moved the code from the example to my own project and now it crashes. In the example project, strings resolve, but in my project they don't.

Comment: Obviously I would like to known why the two projects are different compared to how they resolves strings in the manifest file.

Comment: I just figured out that another error was the reason for the crash. When it was fixed, my own project does not crash anymore and run as expected although the strings do still not resolve.

Answer (score 0):

The Flutter editor in Android Studio doesn't provide proper lint checks for Android code. If the Flutter app runs fine without issues, then it should be fine. To view with proper lint check for Android, open the Android Manifest file, then click on `Tools > Flutter > Open for Editing in Android Studio`

[image: Android Editing]